# WordPress Plugins Feed Error, but I'm not asking for a plugins feed

Tags: rss, feed, simplepie

I'm getting this error on dozens of my sites:

> PHP Notice: A feed could not be found at `http://wordpress.org/plugins/rss/browse/popular/`. A feed with an invalid mime type may fall victim to this error, or SimplePie was unable to auto-discover it.. Use force_feed() if you are certain this URL is a real feed. in `path/to/wp-includes/class-simplepie.php` on line 1555

I don't know where this is coming from. I have no plugins installed other than my own, so this must be a WordPress core thing where it's trying to show me popular plugins but is referring itself to a dead link. Is there any way to disable this?

*UPDATE*

I found where WP core is introducing this feed. It's in `wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php` in the `wp_dashboard_primary()` function.

Answer (score -2):

Check if `php-curl` is installed on your server.
These are php extensions that need to installed for wordpress server

```
php-curl php-gd php-mbstring php-xml php-xmlrpc php-soap php-intl php-zip
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem? WordPress doesn't use curl, and the error message isn't related to it.